# How to use multer to upload file/to do Post in form-data?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, routes, multer, form-data

This is the productsModel.js file

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var productsSchema = new Schema({
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      cost: {
          type: Number
      },
      product_imagePaths: [{
          type: String
      }]
    });

module.exports = mongoose.model('Products', productsSchema);
```

And this is the code of my productsController.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Products = mongoose.model('Products');


exports.uploadProducts = function(req,res) {
    var new_product = new Products(req.body)
    new_product.save(function(err,product){
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
         }
         res.status = 200;
         res.json({
            "status":"success"
         });
     }); 
};
```

productsRoutes.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function (app) {
  var productsController = require('../controllers/productsController');

  app.route('/products')
    .get(productsController.fetchAllProducts)
    .post(productsController.uploadProducts);
};
```

In my server.js

```
// mongoose instance connection url connection
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/abcd', {
    useMongoClient: true
}); 


 // body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true }));

// route
var userRoutes = require('./api/routes/userRoutes');
var aboutUsRoutes = require('./api/routes/aboutusRoutes');
var productsRoutes = require('./api/routes/productsRoutes');
userRoutes(app);
aboutUsRoutes(app);
productsRoutes(app);
```

Now this works when I'm using `x-www-form-urlencoded`. But since I want to upload a file via the `Post` method(uploadProducts in productsController.js), it can be done only via `form-data`. However, it doesn't work with `form-data`. I read that `multer` can be used for `form-data` upload, but I'm clueless as to how to use it in the following methodology.

Comment: Did you use any framework to write client part ?

Comment: I'm using angular 4.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `multer` as middleware before calling your `uploadProducts` function.

Here is an example setup for `productRoutes.js`

```
'use strict';
 const multer = require('multer')
 const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
 const upload = multer({
      storage: storage,
      limits: {
        fileSize: 5000000,
        files: 1
      }
    })
module.exports = function (app) {
  var productsController = require('../controllers/productsController');

  app.route('/products')
    .get(productsController.fetchAllProducts)
    .post(upload.single('img'), productsController.uploadProducts);
};
```

This will create a `Buffer` of your image which you can access in your `productsController.js` with `req.file.buffer`.

Note that `upload.single` is a built in function for `multer`. Read more about other functions [here](https://github.com/expressjs/multer.). Also `img` needs to match the name of your input field, i.e. `<input type="file" name="img">`

This is just one of many one ways to do it. Hope it helps!